# SwitchResX broke my color profile, how to restore?

Tags: color

I wanted to try SwitchRes X and I installed it. It broke my color profile. Now my screen look pink and I cannot calibrate. If I go to my color profile it shows:

[image: Color Profile]

and if I click on calibrate it shows:

[image]

and I removed the application. It didn't fix my problem. I tried to find the original color profile and it is gone in <~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles> or <~User/Library/ColorSync/Profiles>.

Besides reinstall the whole system, is there a way I can restore factory color profile? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `~User/`? ~ is the home folder; / is the drive root. Try copying the file from /Library/ColorSync/Profiles (from the root of the disk, e.g. Macintosh HD).

Comment: ~User means user's folder. For example admin or something you named. The profiles in /Library/ColorSync/Profiles are gone.

Comment: I uploaded the Color Profiles from my Mac. You can get them here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0q39z18q880ni3/Color%20Profiles.zip. Put them in /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/. Then select them in the Display pref pane. If that doesn't work, create a new user account and look in the Display pref pane using that account and see if it is there. PS: Make sure to uncheck the check box that says "Show profiles for this display only"

Comment: You should make it an answer so I can close this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Per campyguy‘s post in https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/switchresx-cannot-remove-fully.1893707/, here goes how to get rid of the annoying "SwitchResX" prefix.

- Open Terminal and enter the following Command:
  ioreg -lw0 | grep IODisplayPrefsKey
- Return of last step should be ended like: ... AppleBacklightDisplay-610-a031, remember the "610" and "a031" hints.
- Go to folder "System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides"
- Find the file folder "DisplayVendorID-610" as per the hint.
- Edit the file "DisplayProductID-a031" in text editor with super admin permission (such as "sudo vi" command), delete the "SwitchResX" word in the file.
- Reboot. (Don't forget to delete SwitchResX profile files in your ColorSync folders /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/ and ~/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/

Hope this finds you well.